# How can I change the view in magneto based upon device size, i.e. , mobile or desktop?

Tags: magento, responsive-design

I am trying to change the product view of my magento ecommerce site based on whether the device is mobile(list view) or desktop(grid view) but am unable to find a solution. I have found https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect but am unable to apply it for my purpose. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the Magento extension mentioned under 3rd party modules? https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect#3rd-party-modules--submit-new

Comment: That is the same extension that I have mentioned. I am facing trouble using it. Can you please explain?

Comment: The "best" option in terms of modern design principles is to write your designs using responsive breakpoints etc, so your templates will work on any device.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible by Match Expression for theme. you need to create different css for mobile device. Please check below link

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/